# insert query with varchar as data type for primary key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, primary-key, varchar

The program is not accepting the query given below-

```
 public class loginDaos {

       public void create(loginBean bean) {
           ConnectionPool c = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
           c.initialize();
           Connection con = c.getConnection();
           try {
               String sql = "INSERT INTO login VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
               PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
               pstmt.setString(1, bean.getCode());
               pstmt.setString(2, bean.getUserid());
               pstmt.setString(3, bean.getPassword());
               pstmt.setString(4, bean.getPosition());
               pstmt.executeUpdate(sql);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }


   public static void main(String args[]) {
       loginDaos ld = new loginDaos();
       loginBean lb = new loginBean("representative", "rep7", "rep7", "r");
       ld.create(lb);

   }
   }
```

The table is:

```
 CREATE TABLE login
( userid char(25);
  password varchar(45),
  code char(5),
  position char(),
  PRIMARY KEY (code)
 );
```

I have currently kept the value of userid,password, code and position as String.The stack trace is:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1564)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1485)
    at login.loginDaos.create(loginDaos.java:33)
    at login.loginDaos.main(loginDaos.java:42)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a `PreparedStatement`, then you should use the `executeQuery()`, `executeUpdate()` or `execute()` method that does not take a `String` parameter.

So to fix the problem use:

```
// ....
pstmt.setString(3, bean.getPassword());
pstmt.setString(4, bean.getPosition());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

The MySQL driver implementation has a bug, because the [JDBC specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) states that the methods accepting a string should throw an `SQLException` when called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement` implementation. In this case it only throws the exception because it tries to execute the parametrized query directly.

Comment: Thank you! will always remember this concept now!!